# Is there a pattern for grouping templates via includes?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I'm creating a new project, and I'd like to namespace a few of my helpers for sightly. These helpers are "template.html files".  I'm currently calling them with the normal pattern of:

```
<sly data-sly-use.MyHelper='MyHelper.html' data-sly-call="${MyHelper.tmpl @ args..}"/>
```

What I'm appreciating about Sightly is the fact that I can do something like this:

---

**templates.html**

```
<template data-sly-template.one>1</template>
<template data-sly-template.two>2</template>
```

**main.html**

```
<sly data-sly-use.tmpls="templates.html"/>

one: <sly data-sly-call=${tmpls.one}/>
two <sly data-sly-call=${tmpls.two}/>
```

---

What I would like to set up is:

**library.html** (includes more modular template functionality)

```
<sly data-sly-import="one.html"/>
<sly data-sly-import="two.html"/>
```

**main.html**  (imports library)

```
<sly data-sly-use.libs="library.html"/>

one: <sly data-sly-call=${libs.one}/>
two <sly data-sly-call=${libs.two}/>
```

---

I have tried a couple variations of the latter to see if there was already something OTTB that's supported. Perhaps I was just hooking it up incorrectly, but does anyone know if this is possible?

thank you,

Brodie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTL Spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#22103-examples):

> When templates are located in a separate file, they can be loaded with data-sly-use

You are already doing this in your working example with `data-sly-use` and `data-sly-call` in your `main.html` to the `data-sly-template` in your `template.html`. You just need to do it one more time in your `library.html`.

**main.html** (imports library)

```
<sly data-sly-use.libs="library.html"/>

one: <sly data-sly-call=${libs.one}/>
two <sly data-sly-call=${libs.two}/>
```

**library.html** (includes more modular template functionality)

```
<template data-sly-template.one>
    <div data-sly-use.one="one.html" data-sly-call="${one.one}"></div>
</template>

<template data-sly-template.two">
    <div data-sly-use.two="two.html" data-sly-call="${two.two}"></div>
</template>
```

**one.html**

```
<template data-sly-template.one>this is one</template>
```

**two.html**

```
<template data-sly-template.two>this is two</template>
```

This will allow you to import all your helpers via one `data-sly-use` expression while keeping your helper templates in separate files just as you asked for, even if the intermediary `library.html` isn't as succinct as you probably wanted.

Comment: I was really hoping for a solution that didn't involve redefining the templates in library.html. But I think this is the only way to do it right now. I think that it would be worth it at this point to do stuff like define templates in a single file and maybe include partials as needed into those templates. Then name the files accordingly, like CommonUtils.html, JsonUtils.html, etc, etc, etc. Thank you!